# How to compile a file using vim-latex or vimtex?

Tags: vim-latex

How does one compile a .tex file from within vim using either vim-latex or vimtex?
In both cases the documentation say to 'do' \ll, but I have no idea what this means.
If I press : and then type \ll I get an error (E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &).

If I just run pdflatex on my .tex file it compiles fine, so it's not a problem with my texlive installation.

Answer (score 2):

What it means to 'do' \ll, is actually just to go to Command mode (press Escape if you're in insert mode) and hit those keys without using :

Comment: Of course I figure this out right after posting my question. If this question is not useful to anyone, maybe it's best to just delete it...